# Visual Studio (& Resharper) mulitiple choices to import same namespace?

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and Resharper 2016.1.  While typing a Linq line I got a popup for multiple choice for the same namespace ?

code

```
 var query =
                from c in context.Courses
                where
```

on hitting 'where' I got Import Namespace:
System.Linq
System.Linq

I just hit enter and then enter but it didn't add a namespace, I had to select the bottom one to add it.  Is there a bug ?

Comment: I recommend you to post this question in Resharper forumns. You might not get much help on stackoverflow about this.

Comment: Try updating to 2016.3... before anything else... Thes ekinds of things tend to be short lived... But can suddenly appear when running an older version of R# with a new version VS.

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to check both the namespaces which you were getting to verify if the method or property you are trying to use is available in both the namespaces. It may also occur if you are using custom libraries. If it is a bug then I think its also better to post on the resharper forums as @DarkKnight suggested.